# Líneas feas en espacios entre li dentro de un nav

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo mi primer `nav` y veo que tiene líneas feas en el centro de cada espacio.

¿Cómo quitar esas líneas?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: #092327;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 3px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: rgb(2, 2, 2);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="inedx2.htm">inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contenido</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pone el estilo del <li>

Comment: comparte el html y el estilo de los elementos dentro del nav

Comment: le estás dando un background al texto... y ese background no ocupa todo el ancho, de la cual deja espacios entre las líneas y deja visible el fondo de atrás (o lo que haya atrás).

Comment: Como es HTML + CSS, podés insertar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma. El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: @MauroAguilar Porque lo pones ahora en imagen?

Comment: Si estás tratando de dar esos estilos a todos esos elementos, debes separar los selectores por comas ( , ), de lo contrario dale un text'decoration:none; background: none; a los elementos li, debería de verse así
li{
     text-decoration: none;
     background: none;
}

Comment: En el snippet, con el código que compartiste se ve bien... Te sugiero editar la pregunta y agregar el `CSS` restante para tratar de replicar el problema.